# encountering a scrolling issue where individual components or images within component are also scrolling independently,why?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, mern

im working on mern stack use tailwindcss for styling,im encountering a scrolling issue where individual components or images within your TelecomsStrategy component are also scrolling independently.I mean i try to scroll to bottom but suddenly it starts scrolling img or text component,i dont know why,its happeng at consulting page and  here is link to demo:

https://anita-impel-website5.vercel.app

```
<div style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }} className="w-full h-[820px] bg-black  flex justify-center items-center pointer-events-none">
        <div className="w-[90%] h-full items-center flex justify-items-end">
          <div style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }} className="w-[730px] bg-zinc-900 z-10 flex flex-col gap-5 text-white p-[90px]">
            <h1 className="text-4xl">Telecommunications Strategy</h1>
            <div className="border-[1px] h-[1px] w-[60px]"></div>
            <h2 className="text-2xl">Get It Right, First Time.</h2>
            <p className="text-gray-500 leading-8">
              An effective telecommunications strategy can revolutionise your
              business, helping achieve your corporate objectives, increase
              efficiency across the organisation and provide the foresight to
              meet changing demands.
            </p>
          </div>
            <img
            style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
              className="pointer-events-none absolute w-[920px] object-cover right-[70px] h-[566px]"
              src="/CS.png"
            />
        </div>

      </div>
```

i already tried overflow hidden and on,nothjing works

Comment: Please provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Linking a live website is not acceptable because as soon as you fix the issue on the website the question will no longer be useful to future users having a similar problem. Also note the bug is not reproducible on the website you linked. What OS + browser are you using?